# Execution time of each query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In column y I want to return query serial number. I know that it's not right, but I have no idea how can I do this.

```
WITH '
MATCH (a:authors{name:"Lui Lis"})-[:`WROTE`]->(b:papers)-[:`REFERS_TO`]->(c:fieldsofstudy)
RETURN c.name AS field_of_study, count(b) AS number_of_papers
' AS query
UNWIND RANGE(0, 4) AS i
WITH i, query, datetime.realtime().epochMillis AS start
CALL apoc.cypher.doIt(query, NULL) YIELD value
WITH i, MAX(datetime.realtime().epochMillis-start) AS execTime
WITH collect(execTime) AS per_query_time, AVG(execTime) AS avg_time
UNWIND per_query_time AS x
RETURN x, RANGE(0, 4) AS y, avg_time
```

Can you please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you mean by a "serial number".

If you want `y` to be the same as `i`, this query should work:

```
WITH '
  MATCH (a:authors{name:"Lui Lis"})-[:`WROTE`]->(b:papers)-[:`REFERS_TO`]->(c:fieldsofstudy)
  RETURN c.name AS field_of_study, count(b) AS number_of_papers
' AS query
UNWIND RANGE(0, 4) AS i
WITH i, query, datetime.realtime().epochMillis AS start
CALL apoc.cypher.doIt(query, NULL) YIELD value
WITH i, MAX(datetime.realtime().epochMillis-start) AS execTime
WITH COLLECT({x: execTime, y: i}) AS per_query_times, AVG(execTime) AS avg_time
UNWIND per_query_times AS z
RETURN z.x AS x, z.y AS y, avg_time
```

If you want `y` to be the index of each query time (across all `i` values), replace the last 3 lines of the above query with:

```
...
WITH COLLECT(execTime) AS per_query_times, AVG(execTime) AS avg_time
UNWIND RANGE(0, SIZE(per_query_times)-1) AS y
RETURN per_query_times[y] AS x, y, avg_time
```

Comment: Thank you again)) Can you tell me how can I return not 5 values of avg_time, but only one?

Comment: You are currently asking for every x/y pair to be returned in a separate row, so `avg_time` also has to be in each row. If you want only a single row to be returned, then you can just return `per_query_times` and `avg_time` without unwinding anything (assuming you don't really need `y`). If you want something else, create a new question with sufficient detail (like what `y` is supposed to represent).